# Error in uploading APK : you uploaded an APK with an invalid signature error from APK signer error minimum signature scheme for target SDK

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services, android-app-signing, targetsdkversion

I was trying to upload my APK having targetSDK version as 30 on Google Play store but it is restricting me to upload the APP and giving error  "you uploaded an APK with an invalid signature error from APK signer error minimum signature scheme for target SDK" .
Please help me with this issue.
My Project is in Eclipse and I build my APK from Eclipse itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sign your APK with `apksigner` (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner), not `jarsigner`, and ensure to enable **v2 signing**, which is required in targetSdk 30.

Comment: Thanks for your response but could you please guide me more on this , because when I am opening the link it is showing me how to use the apksigner. But I am not able to figure out how to download the apksigner.

Comment: `apksigner` is part of Android SDK Tools. I'm not familiar with Eclipse Android development, but it should be part of the Android installation.

Comment: Thank you for your help.